# How do I make "Center location on Map" work?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am new to programing.
I have found the code below and it does everything but center location.(zoom in, map, blue dot all work.)
If I run in simulator, (city run) the blue dot just runs off the page.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self

        map.showsUserLocation = true

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("NotDetermined")
        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("AuthorizedAlways")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("AuthorizedWhenInUse")
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.first!
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 500, 500)
        map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the `userTrackingMode` property on the map view?

Comment: Thank You Xoudini  I am new to programing and don't know anything about userTrackingMode so I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: `yourMapView.userTrackingMode = .follow` automatically centers the user when location services are on, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode).

Comment: Or alternatively [`setUserTrackingMode(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1616205-setusertrackingmode).

Answer (score 0):

Delete your implementation of

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
```

Just get authorization, set `map.showsUserLocation = true`, and stand back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Swift 3 code that works and is tested. It loads mapView, ask user's permission and zoom in into his location.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.mapType = .standard
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion (center:  location,span: span)       
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohsen  I get an error when I copy and paste your code Cannot assign value of type "ViewController" to type "MKMapViewDelegate?"

Comment: Add MKMapViewDelegate as a protocol to your viewController, or remove mapView.delegate = self from your code and you should be good to go, let me know what happens

Comment: or map.delegate = self since you named it map in your code.